# include other layout with java code

Tags: android, include

I used include layout in my android project to load another activity to main activity but include layout just load xml file and not load java code related to activity.

How to i can load both xml and java file code ?

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/actfooter" />
```

Comment: post your code, its not clear question

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you asking about including layout inside another layout?

Comment: i want to include an activity (such xml and java file) to another activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **include** the layout by using `<include> tag`

just `extends` the activity with your current activity.

For ex- `class MainAcitivity extends includeAcitivity` to work with the code of your `includeActivity`.

Comment: thankyou; but if i have several include how to i do it ?

Comment: can you describ more or give a link

Comment: @HamidTB have you heard about Fragments? this is you are looking for

Comment: @HamidTB you can also use fragment to make multiple includes http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Answer (score 0):

boss as you use `<include>` tag that means you are inflating the view part and the xml you are inflating in your layout will be accessible in your activity.

You have to write code in activity in which you are inflating.

as per your expectation you must use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).